# Utilizar una variable introducida por usuario y realizar calculos con ella plsql

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, oracle-21c

necesito ayuda con este ejercicio de plsql, el mismo deberia de permitir al usuario introducir un nro y calcular si es par o impar utilizando restas sucesivas,no me arroja ningun error pero no realiza lo que deberia hacer, este es el resultado que obtengo.

```
Introduzca un valor para n: 5
antiguo   2:   NUM NUMBER(4) := &N;
nuevo   2:   NUM NUMBER(4) := 5;

Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.
```

Esto empezando con lo basico asi que agradeceria mucho su ayuda, utilizo sql plus

```
DECLARE 
  NUM NUMBER(4) := &N;
  DIV NUMBER(1) :=2;
  REST NUMBER(3):= NUM;
  BEGIN
    WHILE REST-DIV>=0 LOOP
    REST := REST - DIV;
    END LOOP;
    IF REST = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EL NUMERO ES PAR');
    ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EL NRO ES IMPAR');
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Base de datos en la que esto se ejecuta? Versión?

Comment: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition

Comment: Esto está dentro de un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Creo que podria ser pero el ejercicio me condiciona que debe ser  PL/SQL anonimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate de activar "serveroutput" para que DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE "pinte" la salida.

Para ello, ejecuta lo siguiente antes de tu código --> set serveroutput on;

Saludos.